# Adding hexadecimal strings in JavaScript efficiently

Tags: javascript, math, hex, modular-arithmetic

In JavaScript, I have two variables that contain a hexadecimal number as a string, each. E.g.:

```
var a = 'a3bc',
    b = '1d0f';
```

Now I want to add them (so, the result should be `'c0cb'`). To make things a little bit easier, let's put some constraints on this:

- The numbers always consist of the same number of digits (i.e., the strings are of same length).
- The numbers are prefixed with `0`s if necessary, so it will be `'001a'`, not just `'1a'`.

On the other side, there are constraints that make things a little bit harder:

- The numbers don't consist of four digits as in the example above, but of 20 digits. Hence you can not simply convert them to decimal, add them, and convert them back. In other words: The numbers are too large for JavaScript's `number` type (this is why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11023640/1333873) does not work).
- There is no overflow allowed. If you add `'ffff'` and `'0001'`, the result shall be `'0000'`, not `'10000'`. In other words: All calculations must be done using a modulo division.

I currently have an algorithm that solves all this, but it's lengthy, not very efficient and everything but elegant. Its idea is to go through the strings character by character, converting them do decimal, adding them, converting them back, remembering potential overflow, and so on. As said, it works perfectly, but I assume it's not the best solution.

How could I solve this in a better way?

PS: I need to do this in Node.js, so if there is a ready-made module available that does this, I'm perfectly fine with this :-)

Comment: You are aware that JavaScript does not convert to decimal format, but to 64bit binary floating point double numbers? Since your input has 80bit, there is no processor based format to store it. But you can fit blocks of 4 or 8 characters with 16bit or 32bit into double floats, which should speed up the string based computation. -- If the carry at the end is not 0, i.e., 1, then add an additional 1 to the string. Here one can stop processing the string as soon as the new carry is 0.

Comment: Actually, it's 160 bits ;-). But, nevertheless, I like the idea. Just have to figure out how to do this in a nice way :-)).

Comment: One Hex-Digit is 4bit, 20 Hex-Digits are 80bit, elementary math. And this block-addition is what was added to the answer of MvG, so I do not have to clone it.

Comment: Don't want to argue about small things, but: One "digit" in an ASCII-encoded **string** is equal to 8 bits, hence in my example 20 hex-digits are 160 bits. Elementary math.

Comment: I'm sorry if I gave the wrong or incomplete impression, I was always speaking about the number represented by the string, not the storage size of the string itself.

Comment: Nevermind, we got each other right now, I think :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest case, you can add one digit at a time, keeping track of carry:

```
var ndigits = 4, i, carry = 0, d, result = "";
for (i = ndigits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  d = parseInt(a[i], 16) + parseInt(b[i], 16) + carry;
  carry = d >> 4;
  result = (d & 15).toString(16) + result;
}
```

If performance is an issue, you might prefer to handle more than a single digit at a time, but then things become either difficult or you have to hard-code the number of digits. Even then, zero-padding stuff will take some work. Here is a solution which does 20 hex digits in three steps, so that no number is more than 32 bits long:

```
function pad(s, n) { while (s.length < n) s = "0" + s; return s; }
d = parseInt(a.substr(13), 16) + parseInt(b.substr(13), 16);
result = pad((d & 0xfffffff).toString(16), 7);
d = parseInt(a.substr(6, 7), 16) + parseInt(b.substr(6, 7), 16) + (d >> 28);
result = pad((d & 0xfffffff).toString(16), 7) + result;
d = parseInt(a.substr(0, 6), 16) + parseInt(b.substr(0, 6), 16) + (d >> 28);
result = pad((d & 0xffffff).toString(16), 6) + result;
```

According to [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/so23293222), this code seems to be three times faster than the above one, at least on some browsers.

Comment: How do I need to adjust the terms `d >> 4` and `d & 15` if I work with blocks or more than one character?

Comment: @GoloRoden: Depends on block size: 4 is the number of bits in a single hex digit and 15 is (1<<4)-1. But your main problem with more than a single character is going to be the zero padding: you can't rely on results having the expected length, and will have to pad with zeros until they do.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to see what you have already but you could use and arbitrary arithmetic library like [BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js).

Javascript

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        bignumber: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/master/bignumber.min'
    }
});

require(['bignumber'], function (BigNumber) {
    function sumHex() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
            length = args.length,
            sum = new BigNumber(0, 16),
            index;

        for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
            sum = sum.plus(args[index], 16).mod('100000000000000000000', 16);
        }

        sum = sum.toString(16);
        while (sum.length < 20) {
            sum = '0' + sum;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    var a = '0000000000000000a3bc',
        b = '00000000000000001d0f';

    console.log(sumHex(a, b));

    a = 'ffffffffffffffffffff';
    b = '00000000000000000001';
    console.log(sumHex(a, b));
});
```

Output

```
0000000000000000c0cb
00000000000000000000
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/snS9X/)