# Adding large hexadecimal strings in PHP

Tags: php, math, hex

I need to add two hexadecimal strings in PHP and return the result as a hexadecimal string. I am currently using the following code:

```
$s1='f452f5a90e5dc303ab2b1ed139d90782fe98f0694f8c7bf88cade835';
$s2='74392c4cfc18badea29a1048f427c602c56e5d2fdff0860878e67c92';

$sum = hexdec($s1)+hexdec($s2);
$sum1 = dechex ($sum);

echo $sum."<br>";
echo $sum1;
```

The program returns the following as output:

```
3.7970072233566E+67 
0
```

Is there a way I can perform hex calculations in a better way in PHP?

Comment: You will need to manually calculate, using the same kind of operations as you would if you were working this out on paper (add the 5 and the 2 to get 7. Add the 9 and the 3 to get c. Add the 8 and the c to get 4, carry 1...)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23291901/1468366) is asking essentially the same question using JavaScript instead of PHP. Its answers should apply here as well.

Comment: How would I do that in a program? Do I add corresponding characters of the two strings?

Comment: maybe this link will helps you http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php#90309

Answer (score 3):

The numbers are too large for PHP's integer data type. Having the [`bcmath`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.bc.php) extension, and [those nice functions from the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php#99130), you can use the following code:

```
function bchexdec($hex) {
    if(strlen($hex) == 1) {
        return hexdec($hex);
    } else {
        $remain = substr($hex, 0, -1);
        $last = substr($hex, -1);
        return bcadd(bcmul(16, bchexdec($remain)), hexdec($last));
    }
}

function bcdechex($dec) {
    $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
    $remain = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);

    if($remain == 0) {
        return dechex($last);
    } else {
        return bcdechex($remain).dechex($last);
    }
}

$s1='f452f5a90e5dc303ab2b1ed139d90782fe98f0694f8c7bf88cade835';
$s2='74392c4cfc18badea29a1048f427c602c56e5d2fdff0860878e67c92';

echo bcdechex(bcadd(
    bchexdec($s1), bchexdec($s2)
));
```

which outputs:

```
1688c21f60a767de24dc52f1a2e00cd85c4074d992f7d0201059464c7
```

Answer (score 2):

Porting [my own answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293222/1468366) to PHP:

```
$ndigits = max(strlen($s1), strlen($s2));
while (strlen($s1) < $ndigits) $s1 = "0$s1";
while (strlen($s2) < $ndigits) $s2 = "0$s2";
$carry = 0;
$result = "";
for ($i = $ndigits - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  $d = hexdec(substr($s1, $i, 1)) + hexdec(substr($s2, $i, 1)) + $carry;
  $carry = $d >> 4;
  $result = dechex($d & 15) . $result;
}
if ($carry != 0) $result = dechex($carry) . $result;
```

Tested on [ideone](http://ideone.com/xKtS5a).

Answer (score 1):

The fact is the maximum return of dechex is :

> ffffffff

See [documentation of dechex()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

So it's pretty normal that it returns you 0 ^^

Hope i helped a bit :p