# How do I change the color of all text and backgrounds with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to write a script to reduce eye strain, which converts the color of all text on a page and all backgrounds for each element. (I guess the backgrounds would become darker and the text would then have to become lighter).
Are there any simple javascript techniques for making global changes to all elements on a page? Or would I have to somehow cycle through every element and check what the text color and background color are for that element (and how would I go about this if so)?
I realise there are probably different options with different levels of complexity, it would be interesting to have an outline of the various ways.

Comment: @blex that will make colors of all elements the same, and can be done with css even simpler `*{background:#333 !important;}`. what op wants is to alter the page's contrast by changing the colors based on their value.

Comment: Ok, I did not get that part.

Comment: You can take a look at my snipped, This should point you in the right direction. Just add the function and you should be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you need to check each element's color individually, there is no global way of doing it with vanilla javascript.

you still need to select all elements and check their colors individually with a loop.

while you are going through the elements, you need to retrieve their **"computed"** colors, and alter them according to your requirements:

the snippet below will alter the contrast of the elements, making their background darker and text lighter, this can be adjusted via the global variable `contrastChange` according to your needs.

```js
  var pageElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");

  //define a how much to change the contrast from 0 to 1

  var contrastChange = -0.3;

  //loop through the elements
  for (var i = 0; i < pageElements.length; i++) {
    //get the element's computed styles
    var elementComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(pageElements[i], "");
    //adjust the color
    var elemAdjustedColor = AdjustColor(elementComputedStyle.color, -contrastChange / 2);
    //adjust background color
    var elemAdjustedBGColor = AdjustColor(elementComputedStyle.backgroundColor, contrastChange);

    //set the new colors
    pageElements[i].style.color = elemAdjustedColor;
    pageElements[i].style.backgroundColor = elemAdjustedBGColor;
  }


function AdjustColor(color, brightness) {
  console.log(color);
  //the computed colors are retrieved as rgb(,,) for color attribute and
  //rgba(,,,) for background color, so we break them into
  //red green and blue components and adjust them according to the brightness
  var digits = /^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)$/.exec(color);
  
  //****UPDATE****
  //sometimes the color might be reported not by its rgb components, 
  //but rather by name like "transparent". in that case return the color unchanged
  //**************
  if (digits != null) {
    //adjust the colors
    var red = parseInt(digits[1]) + 255 * brightness;
    var green = parseInt(digits[2]) + 255 * brightness;
    var blue = parseInt(digits[3]) + 255 * brightness;
    //if color was rgba and had alpha component, we blend the color 
    //with white (because we dont know what was the color behind this element
    //and we are too lazy to check
    if (digits[4] != undefined) {
      alpha = 1 - digits[4];
      red = Math.round((alpha * (red / 255) + (alpha)) * 255);
      green = Math.round((alpha * (green / 255) + (alpha)) * 255);
      blue = Math.round((alpha * (blue / 255) + (alpha)) * 255);
    }
    // keep them in the 0-255 range
    if (red > 255) red = 255;
    if (red < 0) red = 0;
    if (green > 255) green = 255;
    if (green < 0) green = 0;
    if (blue > 255) blue = 255;
    if (blue < 0) blue = 0;

    return "rgb(" + Math.round(red) + "," + Math.round(green) + "," + Math.round(blue) + ")";
  } else {
    return color;
  }
};
```

```html
<span style="background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);">teasd asd asd ast</span>
<span style="background-color:#ffee99;">tesasdas dasd asd t</span>
<span style="background-color:#aaeecc;">teasd asd asd asd sst</span>
```

Comment: Very nice, but this doesn't seem to work with the google site. Is this type of script limited to certain sites?

Comment: @kotozna it works quite well with google in fact, can you be more specific? keep in mind that it does not change image colors, only background & text color

Comment: I'm running this through Greasemonkey in Firefox 38.0.5. Nothing happens on the google.com site (but many other sites are nicely modified)

Comment: @kotozna i have downloaded and tested greasemonkey. it seems that google uses a stronger certificate and firefox wont allow greasemonkey to run any scripts there. for the sake of testing however, you can copy my script and paste it into the firefox dev console (F12 key), and you will notice the changes to the website.

Comment: The script listed here in the other answer (by Nick Russler) does seem to work on the google site, but for some reason yours doesn't. (I have tried your script in tampermonkey on chrome and it works fine on google's site...)

Comment: @kotonza i am not familiar with either of those plugins, but when i tested it on greasemonkey it simply output an error in the console saying that Google's certificate is higher. I suppose it might be because his script adds a css rule, and mine alters the elements directly which requires a higher certificate that the tempermonkey has and grease monkey doesnt. If you prefer, you can achieve a similar effect using css only, but only if you need to decontrast the page a little bit, on higher values it will turn everything gray and unreadable: `*{-moz-filter:contrast(95%);}`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
var elem= document.querySelectorAll("*");

for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
elem[i].style.setProperty("background", "#000000", "important");
elem[i].style.setProperty("color", "#ffffff", "important");
}
```

This will also overwrite "!important" rules.

You can extend the script easily by retrieving the current value (example: getProperty("background");) and add or replace it. A good function for adding values to a hex value can be seen here: [Working with hex strings and hex values more easily in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023144/working-with-hex-strings-and-hex-values-more-easily-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way should be to create a new style element with javascript and add a rule to this stylesheet to set the font color to black (or whatever you like). This way also new elements that are added to the page dynamically will obey the css rule.

```js
function addCSSRule(sheet, selector, rules, index) {
 if("insertRule" in sheet) {
  sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", index);
 }
 else if("addRule" in sheet) {
  sheet.addRule(selector, rules, index);
 }
}

var sheet = (function() {
 // Create the <style> tag
 var style = document.createElement("style");

 // Add a media (and/or media query) here if you'd like!
 // style.setAttribute("media", "screen")
 // style.setAttribute("media", "only screen and (max-width : 1024px)")

 // WebKit hack :(
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));

 // Add the <style> element to the page
 document.head.appendChild(style);

 return style.sheet;
})();

addCSSRule(sheet, "*", "color: white !important;");
addCSSRule(sheet, "*", "background-color: grey !important;");
```

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}

span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
  <span>Hallo World</span>
</div>
```

Source attribution: http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets