# Google script convert to hex

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets, I want to store the value in a cell as a hexadecimal number.

But using `Utilities.formatString("0x%2x", byte)` stores the literal "0x%2x" in the cell.

Using `Utilities.formatString("0x%2i", byte)` stores "0x [number]" as expected.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Best regards
Stefan

Comment: Perhaps this link will help [https://stackoverflow.com/q/11023144/7215091](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11023144/7215091)

Comment: Well, it certainly suggests a workaround that I will try.
But I still do not understand what is wrong with my attempt at formatString.

Comment: Try to coerce byte to a string with String(byte). I don’t know just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that may do what you want:

```
// function to convert decimal to hexadecimal 
function DecToHex(value) {    
  var result = "";
  while( value != 0 ) {
    var temp = value % 16;
    Logger.log(temp);
    var hex = temp < 10 ? String.fromCharCode(temp+48) : String.fromCharCode(temp+55);
    result = hex.concat(result);
    value = Math.floor(value/16);
  }
  if( ( result.length %2 ) != 0 ) result = "0"+result;
  result = "0x"+result;
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert any [Number](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) into hexadecimal, use `theNumber.toString(16)`.

A simple function to convert, add the prefix `0x`, and limit to two digits will be:

```
function dec2hex(value) {
  return "0x" + (value&255).toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
}
```