# Change color of td on click

Tags: css, angular, html-table, onclick, click

how to make a function when I add click() in my button Validate my cells (td) of Table so put changes of color for example green cell -> green light blue light cell ->blue  red cell -> dark red

```html
<button    class="btn btn-success styled1"  type="button">   Validate </button>
```

Comment: This isn't a place for asking people to code for you. Please provide something you tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

this is the suedo code and you can change it according to your requirements. this is just to give you an idea of how to do it.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="LightBlue">Firstname</td>
    <td class="LightGreen">Lastname</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="LightBlue">whatever</td>
    <td class="LightGreen">youfill</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-success styled1" onclick="changeColor()"  type="button">Validate</button>

<script> 
            function changeColor() { 
              var greenTD = document.getElementByClassName("LightGreen"); 
              var BlueTD= document.getElementByClassName("LightBlue");
              greenTD.style.background = "green"; 
              BlueTD.style.background = "Blue";   
            } 
</script>
```

Comment: but My td is made like that : <tr *ngFor="let row of calendar;">
          <td  *ngFor="let col of row"  class="mycell"  ">

Comment: If you only wish to lighten or darken the color. It can be done by manipulating the Hexadecimal Values of colors. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023144/working-with-hex-strings-and-hex-values-more-easily-in-javascript) to see the function of adding or subtracting Hex Values. you can add **ffffff** to lighten and **000000** to darken the color. implement this in your onClick Function.

Comment: @Mohamedh btw, how are you implementing different colors to different cell?

Comment: when I click on a cell there is a pop up that appears and I choose a color green red blue ect ... and the box changes color my colors are CSS classes and initially all the cells of the table are green

Comment: how to make my button recognize my function change color which is in my script

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td [ngClass]="buttonClicked ?'yourClass':''">Firstname</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-success styled1" onclick="buttonClicked = !buttonClicked"  type="button">Validate</button>
```

you can use like this ngClass that is you need to initialize the buttonClicked in your TS file and make it initially as false
it will work

Comment: I tried that but it changes the color of all the boxes not just the red boxes for example?

Comment: oaky so now you  need to pass the clicked index also can you please send your full that loop code i will tell that

Comment: please send me your email for you send